# Appending letters to a list in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, append

I am trying to append the first word of a sentence to an empty list. The current code is below:

```
sentence = input("Enter sentence: ")

subject = []
print (subject)

x = 0
while True:
    letter = sentence[x]
    if letter != " ":
        print (letter)
        subject.append(letter)
        x = x + 1

print (subject)
```

It currently prints this:

```
Enter sentence: Cherries are red fruit

[]
C
h
e
r
r
i
e
s
```

It seems to ignore my attempt to append the result to the empty list... Help, please!

Comment: `x=x+1` is inside an if that says `if letter != " ":` so it will be an endless loop if there is a space in your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better use `for` loop, it's less error-prone:

```
sentence = input('Enter sentence: ')

subject = []
print(subject)

for letter in sentence:
    if letter == ' ':
        break
    else:
        print(letter)
        subject.append(letter)

print(subject)
```

If you want to break a sentence into words, there's a [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method, which can help you in simple cases:

```
words = sentence.split()
first_word = words[0] if words else None
print(first_word)
```

Comment: while loops aren't any more error-prone unless the programmer makes them have an error

Comment: @depperm, of course, and programmers really like to make those errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `split()` function instead of appending one letter at a time:

```
sentence = input("Enter sentence: ")
split_sentence = sentence.split(" ")
subject = []
subject.append(split_sentence[0])
print (subject)
```

or even more simplier:

```
sentence = input("Enter sentence: ").split(" ")
subject = []
subject.append(sentence[0])
print (subject)
```

or even if you are only wanting one input you don't have to append

```
sentence = input("Enter sentence: ").split(" ")
subject = sentence[0]
print (subject)
```

`split()`, splits a string define by the parameter and returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

With while loop:

```
sentence='Nice weather outside'
subject = []
x = 0
while x < len(sentence):
    letter = sentence[x]
    subject.append(letter)
    x = x + 1
print(subject)
```